# Using SqlDependency for data change events: only the fields in SELECT are fired?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am following this tutorial here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/chatter.aspx of using SqlDependency for changing data changed.

After downloading the tutorial, it works fine with me.

However, If I have this query:

> SELECT [Message] FROM dbo.[Message]
>   JOIN dbo.Person ON id =
>   [Message].Person_ID

The person table structure is: I`D & Name`. If I change the Name in the Person table, that will not holding contents in the [Message].Message but this event is still fired.

So my question is how can this event only fired if there is a new message in the [Message] table? would this be possible to achieve?

Thanks in advance.